# <p:commandButton> not getting scrolled along with the <p:scrollPanel>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsf

I have a `<h:inputText><p:commandButton>`arranged one after the other inside a `<p:scrollPanel>`.
The contents inside the scroll pane are dynamic hence the contents gets added or removed based on certain condition and a  scroll bar is added dynamically.If the contents exceeds the size of the scroll pane scrollbar gets added.

 
The problem is when I scroll the scroll bar the `<h:inputText>` gets scrolled along with the scrollbar but the is not getting scrolled along with  which means the  stays static and its not scrolling up and down.

Here is my code

```
<h:inputText style="width:41%" value="#{xx.selectedid"/>
<p:commandButton value="WebPhone" id="pwebpne" style="margin-left:1em;width: auto; height: 20px;font-size:85%;valign:top" actionListener="#{xx.PhoneSearch}"    oncomplete="window.open('#{xx.pUrl}', '_blank')"
rendered="#{xx.editflg == true"} async="false">
```

I have attached the screenshot of my expectation which is given below :
[image]

It seems to be a kind of browser issue, the same works fine in mozilla firefox, I am using IE 8 where the issue is found.
How to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced `<p:commandButton>` with `<h:commandButton>` button and its getting scrolled.

Comment: After updating the above step, I am facing this issue given here .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218148/jsf-hcommandbutton-does-not-invoke-new-window-from-backing-bean