# JSF- <h:commandButton> does not invoke new window from backing bean

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

MY issue is similar to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611296/open-new-window-using-hcommandbutton) 
I am having an  in XHTML and it calls the backing bean method for invoking a new window with an pre constructed URL.But my problem is its not opening the URL.

My code in the XHTML is given below

---

```
 <h:commandButton  style="margin-left:1em;width: auto; height: 20px;font-size:85%"
value="WebPhone" id="lwebpne"rendered="#{Bean.editCmdActionflg == true and (Bean.selectedSearchSysDetRow.isfeed != '1'  or Bean.selectedOverviewDetails.webPheFlg == false)}"actionListener="#{Bean.webPhoneSearch}"   >
<f:param name="lpid" value="lpid" />
</h:commandButton>
```

---

And my code given in the backing bean

```
public void webPhoneSearch(ActionEvent event) {
        logger.info("webPhoneSearch Method Enter ..");

        String param = "";

        Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

    if (params.get("lpid") != null) {
            System.out.println("coming inside>>>>>");
            // String t_lpid = params.get("lpid");
            String t_lpid = selectedOverviewDetails.getLeadPrgMgrUid();
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(t_lpid);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                param = "this values comes from UI ";
            }
        }
// below is a  URL where the window will launch to show the details of a person which we are search for
    Url = "http:// URL for searching a person in webphone" +param;
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute(
                "window.open('" + Url + "')");

        logger.info("webPhoneSearch Method Exit ..");

}<br/>
```

My problem is clikcing the `<h:commandbutton>` does not open a new window   instead the same page reopens in the current window when I click the  `<h:commandbutton>`

Please let me know your suggestions to resolve this issue.

Comment: `h:commandButton` doesn't have attribute `target` try it on your `h:form` as answered in the other question.

Answer (score 1):

as @Alexandre say, <h:commandButton/> doesn't have taget attribute.
use <h:commandLink/>

```xhtml
<h:commandLink target="_blank"
                 style="margin-left:1em;width: auto; height: 20px;font-size:85%"
                 value="WebPhone" id="lwebpne"
                 rendered="#{Bean.editCmdActionflg == true and (Bean.selectedSearchSysDetRow.isfeed != '1'  or Bean.selectedOverviewDetails.webPheFlg == false)}"
                 actionListener="#{Bean.webPhoneSearch}">
    <f:param name="lpid" value="lpid"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

**--- UPDATE: ---**

if you want to trigger some javascript events you can use <f:ajax/>. my sample below.

```
<h:commandButton style="margin-left:1em;width: auto; height: 20px;font-size:85%"
                 value="WebPhone" id="lwebpne" rendered="#{Bean.editCmdActionflg == true and (Bean.selectedSearchSysDetRow.isfeed != '1'  or Bean.selectedOverviewDetails.webPheFlg == false)}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" listener="#{Bean.webPhoneSearch()}" onevent="eventListener"/>
</h:commandButton>
<h:outputScript>
    function eventListener(data) {
        if (data.status == "complete") {
            <!-- YOUR WINDOW ADDRESS HERE -->
            window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');
        }
    }
</h:outputScript>
```

but I don't advise to use popup window. because all of browsers block them. I think [dialog framework](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogFrameworkBasic.jsf) or [lightbox](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/lightBox.jsf) component can be more useful.

Comment: @ bhdrk.Thanks for your suggestions.I want to use <h:commandButton> instead <h:commandLink>.MY issues is with  <p:commandButton> is given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255092/pcommandbutton-not-getting-scrolled-along-with-the-pscrollpanel, so what i did was replacing the <p:commandButton> with <h:commandButton>.Coz' the design issue was occuring in case of <p:commandButton> which I have given in the above URL.<p:commandButton> was working fine by opening a new window ,but <h:commandButton> is not opening a new window.Please let me know your suggestions.